# How to pervent mislead in data or dataloss while updating existing file in C programming?

Tags: c, file-handling

I want to record/update data of a student in "student.dat" binary file. Following is how the struct student looks like:

```c
typedef struct student{
    int roll;
    char name[25];
}stu;
```

Whenever I update the existing data the no. of bytes to be written may be different. For example: if the existing data is of 29 bytes and the new data to be written is 25 bytes. When i open file in "**rb+**" mode both to read and update data (just by placing pointer at the beginning), 25 bytes of data is overwritten but 4 bytes is not overwritten which may mislead data or maybe the problem of data loss may arise.

Yeah, there is the way to overcome the problem opening file again in "**wb**" mode after grabing necessary info or to create tempfile, renaming or removing stuff. But this seems long and kind of boring. I wanna know that is there some way to erase that extra 4 bytes which will help to keep clean record or to delete entire content of file before writing file (before updating) again without opening it again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your code as [mcve] instead of describing it.

Comment: you make claims that your program doesn't fully write a full record. So, what's the point? modify it to do that.

Comment: The structure for your record is a fixed size, so how come you're writing variable size records? You're handling binary data not text therefore don't treat `name` as a string, you must write the trailing `null` characters if your `name` string length is less than 25

Comment: @MarcusMüller, maybe my way of writing is making confusing. I mean to say that "student.dat" has previously recorded 29 bytes of data of student , after making some changes the record of student becomes only 25 bytes. Now, if i write data from beginning first 25 bytes will be overwritten but what happens to rest 4 bytes

Comment: @ChrisBD, as an instance, i don't consider that issue and i am sorry for that but my motive is that for example when i am overwritng 29 bytes of previously recorded data with 25 byte new data, how the rest 4 bytes is handled

Comment: Please explain how your data record becomes 24 bytes instead of 29? Are you writing a different data structure type?

Comment: @MildredGallagher that is impossible given the struct you showed – a student record is always 29 Bytes, by the definition you gave as `struct`. So, your problem is either unrelated with the code you show (and you'd be rightfully asked why you then don't show the code that matters), or you have a massive logic bug in your head.

Comment: @MarcusMüller +Mildred: actually on _most_ implementations `int` is aligned to 4 bytes and thus the struct is padded to 32 bytes -- but the same 32 for all instances

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 didn't want to make things complicated, so omitted the gory details, but: The struct itself isn't padded internally, since the `int` at the start of the struct can be aligned itself. `sizeof` is still 29; and if they're writing things to a file, they'll probably not be padding things to multiple of bytes just be doing something like `write(fd, &johnny_b_goode, sizeof(student)`, so that padding aspect, which is important for in-memory layout, doesn't really apply to file layout.

Comment: can someone explain how padding works?

Comment: @ChrisBD so the length of string in char array does not affect in what bytes of record is written ??

Comment: @MarcusMüller@ChirsBD, I am in this confusion because when I record Name: Robin Warner my Hex Editor decode it as same Robin Warner. And When I write in a same file (using fwrite) where Name :  Robin War again in "rb+" mode after reading previous record using fread, the hex editor decode it  as : Robin War er. The "er" of previous 'Warner" was still there. But when I read the file again it provides me output "Robin War" not "Robin War er"

Comment: @MildredGallagher …  we've wasted a lot of time until you told us there that you're just imagining that your program has this problem, and you're causing the problem by breaking your file with a hexeditor. Your hexeditor overwrites single bytes, your program would generally be designed to overwrite complete student records, boom, no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

When writing data to a file in binary format it is important to ensure that you treat all fields as byte (octet) arrays, in particular you must not use any functions that treat `char []` types as strings and terminates processing at the first `null` chararacter.

Doing so will truncate the data to the first `null` character meaning that data after that point will not be overwritten.

It is also important to ensure that whenever you update your string field (`name`) that you also overwrite the whole field.

It would have helped if you had shown your code, but I suspect that the issue may be due to you using `strcpy` rather than `strncpy` to update the `name` field in your structure instance.

Your structure is defined as

```
typedef struct student{
    int roll;
    char name[25];
}stu;
```

Here's an example of some code that demonstrates an issue with using `strcpy` rather than `strncpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void PrintStringAsHex(char* comment, char* pText);
void PrintArrayAsHex(char* comment, char* pArray, unsigned int arraySize);

typedef struct
{
    int roll;
    char name[25];
}stu;

int main()
{
    stu record={.roll=1, .name="Robert Wagner"};
    
    printf("Original value of record \n");
    printf("roll = %d\n", record.roll);
    printf("name = %s\n", record.name);
    PrintStringAsHex("name string as hex = ", record.name);
    PrintArrayAsHex("name array as hex =  ", record.name, sizeof(record.name));
    printf("\n");

    printf("Treat record.name as a string \n");
    strcpy(record.name, "Robert Wag"); //this will only overwrite array characters upto string length
    printf("roll = %d\n", record.roll);
    printf("name = %s\n", record.name);
    PrintStringAsHex("name string as hex = ", record.name);
    PrintArrayAsHex("name array as hex =  ", record.name, sizeof(record.name));
    printf("\n");

    printf("Treat record.name as an array writing all field chars\n");
    strncpy(record.name, "Robert Wag", sizeof(record.name)); //this will overwrite all array characters

    printf("roll = %d\n", record.roll);
    printf("name = %s\n", record.name);
    PrintStringAsHex("name string as hex = ", record.name);
    PrintArrayAsHex("name array as hex =  ", record.name, sizeof(record.name));
   return 0;
}


void PrintStringAsHex(char* comment, char* pText)
{
    int textLength = strlen(pText);

    printf("%s", comment);
    for(int i=0; i< textLength; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x ", pText[i]&0xFF);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void PrintArrayAsHex(char* comment, char* pArray, unsigned int arraySize)
{

    printf("%s", comment);
    for(int i=0; i< arraySize; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x ", pArray[i]&0xFF);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Original value of record 
roll = 1
name = Robert Wagner
name string as hex = 52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 6e 65 72 
name array as hex =  52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 6e 65 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

Treat record.name as a string 
roll = 1
name = Robert Wag
name string as hex = 52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 
name array as hex =  52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 00 65 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

Treat record.name as an array writing all field chars
roll = 1
name = Robert Wag
name string as hex = 52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 
name array as hex =  52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

You can see in the output above that `strcpy` overwrote the `name` array only as far as, and including, the first `null` in the string whereas `strncpy` overwrites the entire `name` array as it repeats the `null` char until the full stated element count has been reached.

The same care should be taken when writing instances of your `stu` structure to the output file.

The structure, in this case, always takes up 29 bytes (octets) on a 32 bit processor.

Note: the data structure size may change between processors e.g., 29 bytes for 32 bit and 27 bytes for 16 bit, also the order in which bytes are stored in memory for an `int` may differ. This may make the output file machine dependent.

**new code**

Here's a snippet of code to prepare a buffer of binary data that you can then use to buffer your data prior to writing it to your data file.
It demonstrates the issue of memory padding, which you should be wary of when converting data structures and handling binary data.

```
int bufSize = sizeof(record.roll)+sizeof(record.name);
char* bufOut = malloc(bufSize);
memcpy(bufOut, &record.roll, sizeof(record.roll));
memcpy(&bufOut[sizeof(record.roll)], &record.name, sizeof(record.name));

printf("bufSize (sizeof(record.roll)+sizeof(record.name)) = %d\n", bufSize);
PrintArrayAsHex("bufOut = ", bufOut, bufSize);
free(bufOut);
```

You would write `bufOut` to to the binary file.
The output of this - on the machine that I used to run it is:

```
bufSize (sizeof(record.roll)+sizeof(record.name)) = 29
bufOut = 01 00 00 00 52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

To illustrate issues of data ordering and padding in memory, try this code (added to above code, so `bufSize` and `bufOut` already defined):

```
bufSize = sizeof(record);
bufOut = malloc(bufSize);
record.roll = 0x01020304;
memcpy(bufOut, &record, sizeof(record));
printf("sizeof record in memory = %d\n", bufSize);
PrintArrayAsHex("bufOut = ", bufOut, bufSize);
free(bufOut);
```

This gives the output:

```
sizeof record in memory = 32
bufOut = 04 03 02 01 52 6f 62 65 72 74 20 57 61 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Note:

- `record` size is `32`, this is because it has not been defined as
  `packed` and for speed of operation the compiler has padded the data
  so that it fits neatly into 32 bit blocks for the processor.
- `int` is stored in memory in LSB order.

The above is why I have handled `record` elements separately. To avoid vagaries of multi-platform support it is better to manually handle the order in which memory images of integral types are written e.g.

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(int); i++)
{
    bufOut[i] = (record.roll >> i*8) &0xFF;
}
```

This will always ensure that `stu.roll` is written in LSB order.

Comment: it was such a crystal clear explanation. Thanks a lot. Well you all guess were correct except the use of `strcpy`. I had used `snprintf`, but the real job was to encounter all the `null` char as you already told which `snprintf` failed too?

Comment: I think that your issue there is that `snprintf` is really geared to handling strings and the processing of the string to "print" into the destination buffer stops at the first `null` in each string passed to it.